# How to move to the right end the cursor on TextFormField with Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a `TextFormField` widget that displays values on the right end, and every time the field is selected, the cursor is at the beginning of the text, like this:

[image]

What I would like to get, is that the cursor is always displayed on the right side when the field is selected (with a tap or so).
What I tried so far is:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    sellingPriceController.numberValue = 0;

    sellingPriceController.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: sellingPriceController.text.length));
    super.initState();
  }
```

but it seems not working. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a `FocusNode` for that `TextFormField` and listen to its changes. Whenever the focus changes and the `TextFormField` has the focus, move the cursor to the end based on the text inside `sellingPriceController`.

Here's an example:

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late final sellingPriceController = TextEditingController(text: '0');
  late final focusNode = FocusNode();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    focusNode.addListener(onSelection);
  }

  void onSelection() {
    if (focusNode.hasFocus) {
      sellingPriceController.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(
        TextPosition(
          offset: sellingPriceController.text.length,
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    sellingPriceController.dispose();
    focusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: SizedBox(
        width: 300,
        child: TextFormField(
          textAlign: TextAlign.right,
          focusNode: focusNode,
          controller: sellingPriceController,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Additional Note:
if you want to force the cursor to always be on the right side, then also listen to the `sellingPriceController` changes by adding the following to the `initState`:

```
sellingPriceController.addListener(onSelection);
```

With this, whenever the user interacts with the field (insert character, remove one, taps somewhere, etc.), the cursor will always be at the end.

Comment: isn't this should be default behavior?